# A binomial random number generating algorithm that works when $ n \times p $ is very small

Tags: binomial-coefficients, random, binomial-theorem

I need to generate binomial random numbers:

> For example, consider binomial random numbers. A binomial random
>   number is the number of heads in N tosses of a coin with probability p
>   of a heads on any single toss. If you generate N uniform random
>   numbers on the interval $(0,1)$ and count the number less than $p$, then
>   the count is a binomial random number with parameters $N$ and $p$.

In my case, my N could range from $1\times10^{3}$ to $1\times10^{10}$. My p is around $1\times10^{-7}$.

Often my $n\times p$ is around $1 \times 10^{-3}$.

There is a trivial implementation to generate such binomial random number through loops:

```
public static int getBinomial(int n, double p) {
  int x = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(Math.random() < p)
      x++;
  }
  return x;
}
```

This native implementation is very slow. I tried the Acceptance Rejection/Inversion method [1] implemented in the Colt (http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) lib. It is very fast, but the distribution of its generated number only agrees with the native implementation when $n \times p$ is not very small. In my case when $n\times p = 1\times 10^{-3}$, the native implementation can still generate the number $1$ after many runs, but the Acceptance Rejection/Inversion method can never generate the number $1$. (always returns $0$)

Does anyone know what is the problem here? Or can you suggest a better binomial random number generating algorithm that can solve my case.

[1] V. Kachitvichyanukul, B.W. Schmeiser (1988): Binomial random variate generation, Communications of the ACM 31, 216-222.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method is theoretically exact, provided we have a "good" random generator `urand()`$\in[0,1)$. It uses the geometric distribution, i.e. the number of trials until a probability $p$ event occurs for the first time:

```
int getGeometric(double p) {
    return ceil( log( urand() ) / log(1-p) );
}


int getBinomial(int N, double p) {
    int count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int wait = getGeometric(p);
        if (wait > N) return count;
        count++;
        N -= wait;
    }
}
```

However, if $p$ is really small, you may want to replace `log(1-p)` with `(-p)`. Also `getGeometric` exhibits some rounding artefacts when `urand()`is *very* small.

---

The following is roughly based on suggestions in Knuth, *Seminumerical Algorithms*, 3.4.1.F(2). Many improvements especially for `getBeta` and `getGamma` are possible:

```
#define NOTSOMANY 50  
int getBinomial(int N, double p) {
   if (N < NOTSOMANY) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if (urand() < p) count++;
      return count;
   } 
   int a = 1+N/2;
   int b = N+1-a;
   double X = getBeta(a,b);
   if (X>p) 
      return getBinomial(a-1,p/X);
   else
      return a + getBinomial(b-1,(p-X)(1-X));
}


#define SOMELIMIT  3.0  
// must be > 1.0, should be >= 3.0 to make getGamma fast,
// but should also be fairly small to make loop short
double getBeta(double a, double b) {  // a>0, b>0
   if (a < SOMELIMIT && b < SOMELIMIT) {
      for (;;) {
         double Y1 = exp(ln(urand())/a), Y2 =  exp(ln(urand())/b);
         if (Y1+Y2 <1) return Y1/(Y1+Y2);
      }
   } else {
      double X1 = getGamma(a), X2 = getGamma(b);
      return X1/(X1+X2);
   } 
}


double getGamma(double a) {  // a > 1
   for (;;) {
      double Y = tan(Pi*urand());
      double X = sqrt(2*a-1)*Y+a-1;
      if ( X>0 && urand() 
           <= (1+Y*Y)*exp((a-1)*ln(X/(a-1))-sqrt(2*a-1)*Y) )
         return X;
   }
}
```

---

Yet another approach: Instead of $N$ trials with $p$, make $N/2$ trials with $1-(1-p)^2=(2-p)p$ to count how many pairs ($M$, say, with $M\approx Np$ if $p$ is small) of consecutive trials have at least one hit. Among these, the pairs with two hits are $(M,p/(2-p))$ binomially distributed

```
int getBinomial(int N, double p) {
   if (N < NOTSOMANY) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if (urand() < p) count++;
      return count;
   }
   if ( p > 0.5 ) 
      return N-getBinomial(N,1-p);
   else {
      int M = getBinomial(N/2,p*(2-p));
      int result = M + getBinomial(M, p/(2-p));
      if (N&1) 
         if (urand() < p) result++;
      return result;
   }
}
```

I didn't investigate that further, but it is definitely useful only if $Np$ is not big (as each step of the result ultimately comes from some `count++`)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm that gives a good approximation precisely when $np$ is small. The probability that there are exactly $k$ heads is $\binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. Note that
$$
\frac{\binom n{k+1} p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k+1)}}{\binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}} = \frac p{1-p} \frac{n-k}{k+1},
$$
which is small when $np$ is small; hence each term is very large compared to the next term.

Now the conditional probability of having at least $j+1$ heads, given that you have at least $j$ heads, is
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=j+1}^n \binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{\sum_{k=j}^n \binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}} \approx \frac{\binom n{j+1} p^{j+1}(1-p)^{n-(j+1)}}{\binom nj p^j(1-p)^{n-j}} = \frac p{1-p} \frac{n-j}{j+1},
$$
since both sums are dominated by their initial terms.

Therefore you can generate the number of heads this way: provisionally assume there are $0$ heads. Then change $0$ to $1$ with probability $\frac p{1-p} n$, else halt. If you get $1$, change $1$ to $2$ with probability $\frac p{1-p} \frac{n-1}2$, else halt. And so on.